# export widgets value into file with dash

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I'm looking for a solution to export the values of all `dash` widgets.

I have been abble to create a plain txt/csv file but I can' catch the widgets values in the script.
I could make evolve the callback to add all the widgets but it would trigger saving at every modification (I can however make it smarter with n_clicks).

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('is_saved', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('save_bas', 'n_clicks'), ])
def save_file(n_clicks):
    """Decode and store a file uploaded with Plotly Dash."""
    name='file.csv'
    to_export = ['cturn', 'sh_turn', 'sh_pitch', 'dead_turn']
    with open(os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, name), "wb") as fp:
        for item in to_export:
            fp.write('{}:{}\n'.format(item, dash.dependencies.Output(item, 'value')).encode("utf8"))
    return 'As been saved at' if n_clicks!=0 else 'Not saved yet'
```

When I run those lines, the file contents:

```
item1:item1.value
item2:item2.value
...
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could succeed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use `dash.dependencies.State` to not trigger the callback and still get the widget values ([see details here for State](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks))